# Center-justifying Elements in a Form

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my form, specifically the field and text elements within the form, to be center justified, similar to this:

[Form example](http://help.wildapricot.com/download/attachments/46760685/membership_form_details.png?version=1&modificationDate=1337088698247&api=v2)

How would I go about doing that? I've tried doing

```
table > tbody  {
    text-align: justify;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;

}
```

Which just ends up centering everything(except the fieldset, oddly) and doesnt justify anything. Any help would be appreciated.

[My Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgpJMK)

Comment: just wrap your label and input into elem with display: inline-block and remove two text-align in your css, works only last one.

Comment: One way would be wraping up labels and inputs in separate cells, so you can get more flexibility.

Comment: What is "center justified"? There's "justified" or "center" and they're 2 different things.

Comment: A question should contain all the information needed to understand the problem and attempts at solving it, without following any links. In particular you should have explained verbally that you want to put labels and fields in two columns, with fields being of equal width and with labels aligned to the right. Posed that way, it would be an answerable question, but with many relatively simple answers so that the choice between them is primarily a matter of opinion—also including the heavy feelings against some approaches (like a table, the natural approach).

Answer (score 0):

While this is arguably a reasonable case for a table, you could eliminate all the extra markup that tables bring by using the label element set to `display:block` which kind of acts like a table column. I often lay out my forms in the following way. This has the added advantage that at smallscreen views, you can have the label *above* the input by taking away the float.

If you want the input elements on the right side (text, email, textarea, etc) to all look the same, you'll have to style them with specific widths, paddings, font-sizes, etc to override the default browser styles. Otherwise they'll all have different default widths.

```css
label, input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }
label {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 8px;
  clear: left;
  }

input[type="text"] {
  margin: 8px 0;
  }
```

```html
<form>
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name">

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="555-5555">

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email">
 ...
  </form>
```